# how to duplicate and shift dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a structure dataframe like this:

```
customer_name   id   name   level
 "A"             1    "A"    "re"
 "A"             4    "B"    "f"
 "A"             2    "C"    "ro"
 "A"             7    "D"    "n"
 "X"             3    "X"    "re"
 "X"             4    "B"    "f"
 "X"             2    "C"    "ro"
 "X"             7    "D"    "n"
...
```

dataframe that i desire is like this

```
customer_name   id   name   level  upper_id upper_name  upper_level
 "A"             1    "A"    "re"     1         "A"         "re"
 "A"             1    "A"    "re"     4         "B"         "f"
 "A"             1    "A"    "re"     2         "C"         "ro"
 "A"             1    "A"    "re"     7         "D"         "n"
 "A"             4    "B"    "f"      4         "B"         "f"
 "A"             4    "B"    "f"      2         "C"         "ro"
 "A"             4    "B"    "f"      7         "D"         "n"
 "A"             2    "C"    "ro"     2         "C"         "ro"
 "A"             2    "C"    "ro"     7         "D"         "n"
 "A"             7    "D"    "n"      7         "D"         "n"
 "X"             3    "X"    "re"     3         "X"         "re"
 "X"             3    "X"    "re"     4         "B"         "f"
 "X"             3    "X"    "re"     2         "C"         "ro"
 "X"             3    "X"    "re"     7         "D"         "n"
 "X"             4    "B"    "f"      4         "B"         "f"
 "X"             4    "B"    "f"      2         "C"         "ro"
 "X"             4    "B"    "f"      7         "D"         "n"
 "X"             2    "C"    "ro"     2         "C"         "ro"
 "X"             2    "C"    "ro"     7         "D"         "n"
 "X"             7    "D"    "n"      7         "D"         "n"
...
```

my code is like this, but i think it's different from my desire output:

```
df['upper_id'] = df.groupby('customer_name')['id'].shift(-1)
df['upper_name'] = df.groupby('customer_name')['name'].shift(-1)
df['upper_level'] = df.groupby('customer_name')['level'].shift(-1)
```

what should i do?

Comment: How do you achieve your desired output? Can you explain the calculation further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another try using `merge` and other manipulations to remove duplicates.

Code:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df,df,on='customer_name',how='outer',suffixes=("", '_upper'))
df1[['id','id_upper']] = df1[['id','id_upper']].astype(str)
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.to_numpy().sort()
idx = df2.drop_duplicates(keep='first').index
df1 = df1.iloc[idx].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   customer_name id name level id_upper name_upper level_upper
0            "A"  1  "A"  "re"        1        "A"        "re"
1            "A"  1  "A"  "re"        4        "B"         "f"
2            "A"  1  "A"  "re"        2        "C"        "ro"
3            "A"  1  "A"  "re"        7        "D"         "n"
4            "A"  4  "B"   "f"        4        "B"         "f"
5            "A"  4  "B"   "f"        2        "C"        "ro"
6            "A"  4  "B"   "f"        7        "D"         "n"
7            "A"  2  "C"  "ro"        2        "C"        "ro"
8            "A"  2  "C"  "ro"        7        "D"         "n"
9            "A"  7  "D"   "n"        7        "D"         "n"
10           "X"  3  "X"  "re"        3        "X"        "re"
11           "X"  3  "X"  "re"        4        "B"         "f"
12           "X"  3  "X"  "re"        2        "C"        "ro"
13           "X"  3  "X"  "re"        7        "D"         "n"
14           "X"  4  "B"   "f"        4        "B"         "f"
15           "X"  4  "B"   "f"        2        "C"        "ro"
16           "X"  4  "B"   "f"        7        "D"         "n"
17           "X"  2  "C"  "ro"        2        "C"        "ro"
18           "X"  2  "C"  "ro"        7        "D"         "n"
19           "X"  7  "D"   "n"        7        "D"         "n"
​
```

Comment: i think this works and match with my desire output. Thank you @sharathnatraj

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension for duplicated values, added `i` row by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last join DataFrames together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with change order of columns names:

```
df = df.reset_index()

L = [x.iloc[i:].add_prefix('upper_').assign(**x.iloc[i]) 
      for name, x in df.groupby('customer_name')
      for i, y in enumerate(x.index)]

cols = df.columns.tolist() + ['upper_id','upper_name','upper_level']
df = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True).reindex(cols, axis=1)

print (df)
   customer_name  id name level  upper_id upper_name upper_level
0              A   1    A    re         1          A          re
1              A   1    A    re         4          B           f
2              A   1    A    re         2          C          ro
3              A   1    A    re         7          D           n
4              A   4    B     f         4          B           f
5              A   4    B     f         2          C          ro
6              A   4    B     f         7          D           n
7              A   2    C    ro         2          C          ro
8              A   2    C    ro         7          D           n
9              A   7    D     n         7          D           n
10             X   3    X    re         3          X          re
11             X   3    X    re         4          B           f
12             X   3    X    re         2          C          ro
13             X   3    X    re         7          D           n
14             X   4    B     f         4          B           f
15             X   4    B     f         2          C          ro
16             X   4    B     f         7          D           n
17             X   2    C    ro         2          C          ro
18             X   2    C    ro         7          D           n
19             X   7    D     n         7          D           n
```

Comment: why i got an error like this? ```KeyError: (0,)```

Comment: @mk_ - Can you add `df = df.reset_index()` before solution?